# vue-cli npm install error. ELIFECYCLE ENOENT spawn protobufjs

Tags: node.js, spawn, npm-scripts, vue-cli-3

I am trying to install **vue-cli 3** with the given instructions.

```
   npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Environment:

```
WSL
Ubuntu 18
Node 8.12.0
npm 6.4.1
"n" node version manager
```

It appears the problem is node's `child_process.spawn` which is used by the `protobufjs@6.8.8` ***postinstall script***

**See this:** child_process.spawn does not work with npm run scripts on windows [github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3675](http://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3675)

***QUESTION*** is there a way to prevent that postinstal script from running and allowing the rest of the installation and I can somehow run postinstall manually later?

here is the error:

```
stack Error: protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
stack spawn ENOENT
stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/n/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
pkgid protobufjs@6.8.8
cwd /mnt/c/Users/dogbot
Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
argv "/root/n/bin/node" "/root/n/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@vue/cli"
node v8.12.0
npm  v6.4.1
@6.8.8 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
error spawn ENOENT
error Failed at the protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall script.
error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the ignore-scripts flag

```
npm install  @vue/cli -g --ignore-scripts
```

Then I did the same for protobufjs

```
npm install protobufjs  -g --ignore-scripts
```

Finally i manually ran the protobufjs  postinstall script

```
node ~/n/lib/node_modules/protobufjs/bin/scripts/postinstall.js
```

My installation appears to be working correctly now.